# Video call in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, video

When camera is activated in call, outgoing sound will have noise. This is happening with Google meet and Whwereby (both with Firefox and Chromium). Skype too. H/W is HP Notebook 14-am012no. In my opinion this could be also hardware issue.

Comment: Try recording your voice in some software, and see if it persists. Most likely an hardware issue.

Comment: It looks that it is something to do laptop's own camera. By using external camera, no noise. On the otherhand symptoms are different now. Long (voice) delays in calls and ocationaly application locks voice. For exmpale, using netmeeting via browser and after that skype sound to outbound don't work. Yes, still the h/w could be the issue,

Answer (score 0):

Now I have a kind of picture of the situation.

1. Video disturbances to the sound. Most likely h/w issue, external camera ok
2. Other voice problems: USB-keyboard was able to generate some kind of disturbances. Keyboard changed

One lesson learned, USB can cause funny things